# Find coordinates of 2 unknown corners of square inscribed in a circle

Tags: geometry

I have a circle diameter set at D, by a straight line that can be placed at any angle from point P1 to point P2. The actual angle is unimportant.

problem: how to calculate with a formula (not draw) the two other coordinates (say X & Y) of the corners of a square that is inscribed within the circle set by diameter D, using the reference coordinates P1 and P2  and D as the only knowns. The corners of the square would therefore be at P1, P2, X, & Y, and lie on the perimeter of the circle.

goal: to use the two newly calculated coordinates X & Y and P1 & P2 to construct an inscribed square (within the circle defined by D) at the offset angle given by the straight line between P1 & P2.

All help appreciated!

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The center of the circle is at $$(x_c,y_c)=\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}2,\frac{y_1+y_2}2\right)$$
Let's call the radius of the circle $R$, and the angle from the center to $P_1$ is $\alpha$, from the horizontal line. Then the positions of the points with respect to center are:
$$(x_1-x_c,y_1-y_c)=R(\cos\alpha, \sin\alpha)\\(x_2-x_c,y_2-y_c)=-R(\cos\alpha, \sin\alpha)\\(x_X-x_c,y_X-y_c)=R(\sin\alpha, -\cos\alpha)\\(x_Y-x_c,y_Y-y_c)=-R(\sin\alpha, -\cos\alpha)$$
From the first of these four equations you can get $R\sin\alpha$ and $R\cos\alpha$, so all you need to do is to add the corresponding terms to $x_c$ and $y_c$ to get the rest.

Comment: Andrei - great. thank you for your prompt help and expertise. I will try it and update you

Comment: Andrei, is there any other way to get these points without knowing the angle ?

Comment: You don't need the angle directly. Just take $R\cos\alpha$ and $R\sin\alpha$ from the first equation. For example, the cosine term is $0.5(x_1-x_2)$

Comment: Andrei - your solution is perfect, thanks

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted